# How to get wpf button's parent's parent

Tags: vb.net, binding, wpf-controls, parent-child

I want to get a Button's parent's parent. I am able to get the parent using

```
Dim tempB As Button = CType(sender, Button)
Dim g1 As Grid = CType(tempB.Parent, Grid)
```

(in my click handler). But if I do

```
Dim g2 As New Object
g2 = g1.Parent

tempB.Content = g2.GetType
```

I get a `NullReference Exception`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple C# snippet that will give you all the parents of a clicked Button:

```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(GetParents(sender, 0));
    }

    private string GetParents(Object element, int parentLevel)
    {
        string returnValue = String.Format("[{0}] {1}", parentLevel, element.GetType());
        if (element is FrameworkElement)
        {
            if (((FrameworkElement) element).Parent != null)
                returnValue += String.Format("{0}{1}",
                    Environment.NewLine, GetParents(((FrameworkElement)element).Parent, parentLevel + 1));
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```